# "Facebook \ WebDriver \ Exception \ TimeoutException" when using waitFor() in symfony/panther & Laravel

Tags: laravel, symfony-panther

I have a laravel app that is using [symfony/panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther) to scrape js loaded web pages.

Upon running, I always get a timeout exception `Facebook \ WebDriver \ Exception \ TimeoutException` at the `waitFor()` method.

I've tried increasing the `max_execution_time` in my `php.ini` file and also tried doing this in a queue, but I still get the same error

To test I'm using a livewire component

```
public function handle()

{

    $client = Client::createChromeClient(base_path("drivers/chromedriver"), null, ["port" => 9080]);    // create a chrome client

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com');

    $client->waitFor('h1'); // Fails here ***********
    
    $crawler->filter('h1')->text();


}
```

Any ideas what could solve this timeout exception?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the website being visited was not loading the JS due to console errors. Therefore the `waitFor()` never sees its element. The errors were CORS Policy errors and 403 errors. Both due to the browser being automated. Incase you have stumbled on this, the solution that worked for me is to add these flags:

```
$client = Client::createChromeClient(base_path("drivers/chromedriver"), [
    '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
    '--window-size=1200,1100',
    '--disable-web-security',
    '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
], ["port" => 9080,]);
```